# Why does 4-wire resistance measurement change after a period of time?

Tags: measurements, power-electronics, electrical

I have a plug that I am measuring the resistance using the kelvin probe.
The plug is as below. The measurement is taken from the contact point of the plug the other end that has a PCB inside that would be used to eventually attach a cable. In this case NO CABLE.
[image]
I took the measurements again and got a similar result. After a period of time say 10 minutes the measurements eventually change either all values increase or decrease but the cumulative value is similar if I had to measure the plug inserted into a component.

My question is to understand why I see such changes?

I have the probe tip and the plug that is being measured of the same material, so I don't think a thermal affect is causing it. My assumption is that the force that I apply to make contact between the probe and plug makes a difference but how much does this affect, can we quantify it and is there a relation between the force applied to resistance?

Comment: "*I have a plug that I am measuring the resistance ...*" What does this mean? How do you measure the resistance of a plug? Do you mean that you are measuring the contact resistance of a plug and socket? Please edit and post a picture or drawing.

Comment: Edited. The measurement is just for the PLUG by itself.

Comment: "*I am measuring the resistance using the kelvin probe.*" A kelvin measurement would require two independent contacts at each end. What kind of kelvin probe are you using? How are you making contact?

Comment: The kelvin probe that I am using is Keithly Probe 5808. It's a single fixed pin probe with both the source and sensing lead in one. One probe tip would make contact on the contact side and other probe tip would make contact on the PCB point. completing the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Keithly documentation](https://download.tek.com/datasheet/PA-967_C_Jan_2017_k_probes_5808.pdf):

> The ohms current and voltage sensing leads are separately
> connected to the base of the single-pin probe tips.

I'd say that is your problem. Usually for 4-wire you measure the voltage *inside and between* the current connections so that you're not measuring the voltage drop across the connections. The Keithly probe is eliminating voltage drop along the lenght of the wires but not across the contact points.

Try a test on a copper strip or PCB with varying contact pressure.

Comment: I believe the point of a 4-wire probe is to eliminate the voltage drop of the lead. The Voltage drop across the contact points would be very low since the sensing current would be very low. This way the error in measurement would be pretty low as well.